# I want to check whether user is disable in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, principalcontext

I want to check if user is disabled in Active Directory. I have written following code but it is not working.

```
private DataTable IsUserExists(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataTable temp = new DataTable();
        temp.Columns.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
        temp.Columns.Add("DOE", typeof(DateTime));

        try
        {
            using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {

                    UserPrincipal users = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, row["DisplayName"].ToString());

                    if (users != null && (((UserPrincipal)users).Enabled.Value == true))
                    {
                        temp.Rows.Add(row["DisplayName"].ToString(), row["DOE"].ToString()); 
                    }
                }
                return temp;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return null;
        }

    }​
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Probably wouldn't know since your eating them.

Comment: I don't get any errors but it is not filtering the disabled user.. as per my condition it should only store users which are enable.

Comment: How do you know you arent getting any errors? Are you running this in Visual Studio in debug mode? Because currently you are eating all exceptions with the catch return null.

Comment: I have debug the code, there is no exception.

Comment: try using user.Enabled == true

Comment: @DarenDelima I have tried but it is not working. Is there any privileged issue because I have not given username and password in PrincipalContext class.

Comment: What do you mean not working error? or still not filtering? No I don't think so, you are already getting all the users.

Comment: You tried using only users.Enabled == true instead of ((UserPrincipal)users).Enabled.Value == true?

Comment: @DarenDelima it is not filtering, yes i have tried users.Enabled == true instead of ((UserPrincipal)users).Enabled.Value == true

Comment: What I think is you should try checking the active directory and try creating a user and disable it then run your code, still use user.Enabled == true. I have the same code in one of my project the only difference is that part and it is working

Comment: @DarenDelima thanks.